# How can I use the less pre-processor to handle different styles with two divs one after the other?

Tags: css, less

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="float-left inline orderby">
   <div class="arrow up" style="margin-bottom: 2px; margin-left: 2px"></div>
   <div class="arrow down" style="margin-left: 2px;"></div>
   <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="inverse" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 10px;">
</div>
```

I'm trying to use the less pre-processor to create my CSS.

How can I use less to create CSS to remove the styles from this example. In particular I am not sure how to handle the difference between the 1st and 2nd DIV

Comment: I don't see the html code..

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to remove the inline styles?

```
.orderby .arrow, .orderby input {
    margin: 0;

    &.up {
        /* styles for first div */
    }

    &.down {
        /* styles for second div */
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think something like this but I noticed you have two up's and there's nothing for the <input>

Comment: Sorry I got the question wrong and made a little mistake. Anyway, now it should work

Comment: I think there is still a mistake because this checks to see if there's an up or down class as part of the input.

Comment: Yes, it does, but it won't find anything. It will set the margins to zero for the .orderby .arrow and the .orderby input, it then proceeds to see if any of those two has a child element called up or down. In the case of the input it won't find any. I think for such a small case there will be no performance issues

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear exactly what your question is. I can read it two ways:

### (1) You cannot *remove* css set with `style` with LESS

If you actually have a `style` property on your html elements, then that cannot be directly affected by LESS at all (so it cannot be "removed" by LESS). Additionally, the only way to overcome those styles *with LESS* is by using the exact same solution you would have available with CSS, the `!important` attribute (which I ***despise***, but the facts are the facts when it comes to what is available for CSS styling). So this would remove the margins imposed by the `style` for all direct children in your `div` (as your example has):

```
.orderby > * {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

---

**But perhaps you want to know how...**

### (2) You can *move* the code from the `style` to the LESS

In which case, it is something like this:

**LESS**

```css
.orderby {
  .arrow {
     margin-left: 2px;
     &:first-child { /* or could use &.up */
       margin-top: 2px;
     }
  }
  input {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px; 
  }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.orderby {
  .arrow {
     margin-left: 2px
     &:first-child { /* or could use &.up */
       margin-top: 2px;
     }
  }
  input {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px; 
  }
}
```